# Google places api get distance of nearby places in android

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-3

I cannot find way to sort my nearest places according to distance in android. I also want to show that distance on listview with name of places. Can anyone help me to do this.???

Here is my function to search plaaces:

```
public PlacesList search(double latitude, double longitude, double radius, String types)
        throws Exception {

    this._latitude = latitude;
    this._longitude = longitude;
    this._radius = radius;

    try {

        HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
        HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory
                .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(PLACES_SEARCH_URL));
        request.getUrl().put("key", API_KEY);
        request.getUrl().put("location", _latitude + "," + _longitude);
        request.getUrl().put("radius", _radius); // in meters
        request.getUrl().put("sensor", "false");
        if(types != null)
            request.getUrl().put("types", types);

        PlacesList list = request.execute().parseAs(PlacesList.class);
        // Check log cat for places response status
        Log.d("Places Status", "" + list.status);
        return list;

    } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
        Log.e("Error:", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following:

```
request.getUrl().put("rankby", "distance");
```